# Unable to access ISP gateway user interface

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012

I am hoping that someone can assist. I have a Windows 2012 Server that is a domain controller and serves local ip addresses out on our network (DHCP).

Everything is working fine with the exception of accessing the ISP gateway web interface (10.1.10.1). When I attempt to access the Web interface at 10.1.10.1, I typically time out. I experienced one instance today where I received the login screen, but after logging in I received a time out error in the browser.

nslookup 10.1.10.1 results in the following message: "xxxx.xxxx.local can't find 10.1.10.1: non-existent domain." It appears that the address 10.1.10.1 is not being resolved or something is blocking it.

I can successfully ping 10.1.10.1. I can access the internet. I cannot access the UI of the gateway. Unable to telnet - port 80 - could not open connection to the host, but port 80 is receiving requests. Would love some advice. Thanks in advance.

-Cassie

Comment: What kind of device is the gateway at 10.1.10.1?
What is the local DHCP scope?
Have you ever been able to get to the Web GUI of the gateway device?

Comment: Nslookup doesn't have anything to do with it. Looking up an ip address with nslookup is trying to resolve a host name from an ip address and would only work if you have a Reverse Lookup Zone in DNS for the network/subnet in question. It's not related to your connectivity problem.

Comment: The gateway is a Cisco DPC3939B. The DHCP address pool is 10.1.10.10 -10.1.10.200. Yes. I have been able to get to the web gui of the gateway in the past. I was able to access it this morning - just the ui - when i attempted to login, the interface timed-out.

Comment: That's a completely different problem then the one you posed in your question. Not being able to reach the gateway and reaching it but having the interface timeout are completely different problems.

Comment: I do have a Reverse Lookup Zone in DNS set for 10.1.10.in-addr.arpa.

Comment: What changed since the last time you accessed the device?

It sounds to me like either the gateway device is malfunctioning (try rebooting it) or you have another device with duplicate IP 10.1.10.1.

You can test for a duplicate IP by disconnecting the gateway device from the network. Then flush the ARP cache on your mgmt workstation (arp -d -a). Then ping 10.1.10.1 and check your ARP cache (arp -a) for 10.1.10.1

Comment: The Cisco gateway is relatively new (last Tuesday - installed by Comcast - was able to access the gateway web ui at that time). No other changes. Thanks for editing help and the advice, Stephen F.

Comment: Does your Reverse Lookup Zone have a record for the gateway device? At any rate, resolving the ip address to the name isn't relevant to your connectivity problem. connecting to the device by ip address doesn't involve DNS in any way.

Comment: It did not have a record for the gateway device and I agree, resolving the ip address isn't the issue. Thanks.